# Load Distinct Images from array into UITabeView

Tags: iphone, image, uitableview

I am trying to load three different images from an array into corresponding cells in a UITable. So far I have the following code which builds fine crashes when t is run. I fanyone can helps me out I would be very grateful.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
 NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Icon Nightclub", @"Smyhts Bar",
       @"Synotts",nil];
 self.listData = array;


 NSArray *picArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"ArrowLeftDefault.png", @"ArrowRightDefault.png",
       @"events.png",nil];
 self.picData = picArray;


 [array release];
 [picArray release];
 [super viewDidLoad];

}


-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{ 
 return [listData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableIdentifier";
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier];

 if (cell == nil) {
  cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
 }

 NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
 cell.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
 cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row];
 cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;

 cell.imageView.image = [picData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change:

```
cell.imageView.image = [picData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

for something like this:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[picData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

**Explanation:**
Since picData `NSArray` contains `NSString`s, you were passing a `NSString` object to `cell.imageView.image` when it expects an `UIImage` object actually. 
That is why now it creates an image and passes it. (`imageNamed:` method cashes the image)

Comment: You're a faster typer than I am. :) Yes, this is the answer. The code is crashing because the picData array contains an array of strings, not UIImages

Comment: Ah brilliant. Cheers. I should have spotted that. I'm not at this too long. You saved my bacon.

Comment: Thanks Walter, I just added an explanation ;)